# get web service uri from external file in android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, rest

I'm developping an android application that calls rest web services and parse the results to Json object , I want to store the web service URI in a separate file so I added the base uri in the strings.xml file as follows :

```
<string name="BaseRestURL">http://192.168.1.2:8080/SensorRestService/webresources/</string>
```

and to use the url inside tha java code  i used this :

```
 String read = parse.readFeed(R.string.BaseRestURL+"com.rest.entities.user");
```

the problem with this code is that "R.string.BaseRestURL" displays an int code not the real string value so , i cannot access the ressource using this code so any one could help me !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
String read = parse.readFeed(getString(R.string.BaseRestURL)+"com.rest.entities.user");
```

Answer (score 2):

In your activity call :

getString(R.string.BaseRestURL)